# exception while reverse engineering the java code using STAR UML

Tags: uml

I am trying to reverse engineer java code in starUML. But i am getting Unrecoverable Parse error. please tell me reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to swap to a new tool for reverse engineering.
The best tool is EclipseUML omondo but really too expensive. A trick is to download the old zip 30 days evaluation build at: http://www.uml2.org/eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32_eclipseUML2.2_package_may2010.zip

Just unzip and it works immediately for 30 days. This is standalone build including Eclipse and all needed plugins.

You don't need to buy the tool just make your reverse engineering with this evaluation bundle and copy into your documentation what you need.

Answer (score 2):

STAR-Uml is quite old an probably unmaintained. I guess your code uses new features like generics and Star-UML cannot parse them.

Answer (score 1):

The "Unrecoverable Parse error" occurs due to Star UML not able to support Generics in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Star UML doesn't support Java Annotations, try to do reverse engineering after removing the annotations in the code.